# Change the default settings to create new projects

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I have two questions here, both related.

When I create a new project with a blank activity in Android studio the project always creates an app with an  `ActionBarActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

1.How can I change my project defaults to remove this default and just create a project as:

```
public class MainActivity
```

**OR**

2. to update it so its is not creating an app with deprecated code. Please see image.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to reconfigure the content of main activity created by default. Possibly the Google engineers will fix it some time in the future.
What you can do here to save some time is move the caret to the `ActionBarActivity` while being in the `MainActivity.java` file and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The quick fix "Replace with AppCompatActiivty" will pop up and all you'll need to do is hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply it. It's easier than replacing `ActionBarActivity` with `AppCompactActivity` by typing.

Answer (score 1):

For 1. change to `public class MainActivity extends Activity`

For 2. change to `public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity`

EDIT: Creating project without activity.

[image]

Comment: I just understood. You better create it as a class rather than activity. However you need to associate the XML files and specify the activity in Manifest

Comment: For new project, there will be an option to create a project with No activity. Check it out.

Comment: Edited my answer to create without activity